# Issue with ExternalInterface.call in IE

Tags: flash, externalinterface

I am having an issues with ExternalInterface.call to return a value in IE. It is working fine in Firefox. Eventhough I changed the "allowscriptaccess" to "always", still it is not working. 
Is there any thing that I need to change in Flex or the HTML to make this work? or this is a security setting in IE?

Thanks in advance,
Praveen

Comment: You need to provide more details, relevant code samples, what type of data you're returning, etc.

Comment: What ExternalInterface.available says in IE for this case?
Also, try to read this http://mihai.bazon.net/blog/flash-s-externalinterface-and-ie

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can give more code examples... from flex and from javascript.

difference between firefox and IE is very common.

maybe something with capitals? try the `alert()` to test if it works at all.